# MySQL - Create trigger error 1064 near line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a new trigger on a MySQL 8.0 database.
I get the following error when applying via MySQL Workbench...

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
> that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
> use near '' at line 1

Here is the trigger script...

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_set_location_engagement;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_set_location_engagement
BEFORE INSERT ON v2_nc_nip_cap_engagement
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET NEW.water_system_id = (SELECT water_system_id FROM v2_nc_registered_water_systems WHERE NEW.system_name = water_system_name);
SET NEW.province_id = (SELECT province_id FROM v2_nc_province WHERE NEW.province_name = province_name);
SET NEW.island_id = (SELECT island_id FROM v2_nc_island WHERE NEW.island_name = island_name);
SET NEW.area_council_id = (SELECT area_council_id FROM v2_nc_area_council WHERE NEW.area_council_name = area_council_name);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is any error. Can you share the table structure also.

Comment: The trigger text is correct synthactically. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e11fcf2272d927b235a10f5a9ced090 Check if multi-query is allowed by your connector and DELIMITER command is allowed/supported (this is CLI command, not SQL statement).

Comment: You may have extraneous non-printable characters if you're copying/pasting the code from somewhere else. You can try deleting the first characters and type them manually again (or copy the entire thing into [Unicode inspector](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect) and see what shows up).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help folks. The issue was that I was using the Trigger (Object) editor in MySQL Workbench to apply the trigger. When I applied the trigger using the SQL IDE in Workbench, the trigger was applied successfully.